# Why am i getting an unresolved external system error (error LNK2019) for both of my calculation functions?

Tags: c, function

Why am i getting an unresolved external system error (error LNK2019) for both of my calculation functions? 
Error   6   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CalculateAreaRec 
Error   7   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CalcCircleArea referenced 
Error   8   error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals

```
#include <math.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#define PI 3.14159
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS    //to avoid scanf warning or error
/* Function prototype */
int CalculateAreaRec(int length, int width);
double CalcCircleArea(double radius);
int GetInt(void);
int main(void)
{
    //Declared varibles 
    double radius;
    int length;
    int width;
    int GetInt(void);
    {
        // this function gets an integer from the user and returns it
        // this function is called 3 times from main

        //Prompt for the radius of the circle.
        printf("Whats the radius of the circle \n");
        //Get the radius from the keyboard.
        scanf("%lf", &radius);
        //Display the radius and area of the circle onto the screen.
        printf(" The radius is %lf and the area is %.4f \n", radius, CalcCircleArea(radius));
        //Prompt for the length of a side
        printf("Whats  the length of a side of rectangle \n");
        //Get the length from the keyboard
        scanf("%d", &length, CalculateAreaRec(length, width));
        //Prompt for the width of a side
        printf("Whats length of the width \n");
        //Get the width from the keyboard
        scanf(" %d", &width, CalculateAreaRec(length, width));
        //Display the side length, width, and area of the rectangle onto the screen.
        printf(" The side length  is %d the width is %d and the  area of the rectangle is   %d \n ", length, width, CalculateAreaRec);
    }
    double CalcCircleArea(double radius);
    {
        //Calculate the area of the circle (use 3.14).
        return (PI * radius * radius);
    }
    int CalculateAreaRec(int length, int width);
    //takes two arguments (base and height of the triangle) and returns the area 
    {
        return (length*width);
        //takes one argument (radius of the circle) and returns the area
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code has so many mistakes. Please go an read a good book/tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

C doesn't support nested functions.  They all have to live at the topmost level, independent of each other.

Besides that, your `main` doesn't appear to have any code in it to call the other functions.

You're also calling `CalculateAreaRec` incorrectly.  It shouldn't be a parameter to `scanf`, and you need to give it arguments where it's called as a parameter to `printf`.

Comment: how could i call a function

Answer (score 0):

Because you define some functions and then try to declare them inside the `main` method in the wrong way, what you have is

```
double CalcCircleArea(double radius);
int main() {
  ...
  double CalcCircleArea(double radius); // <- this semicolon saves you from a compilation error 
  // because this line is interpreted as a forward declaration and block below as a scope
  {
    ..
  }
}
```

but you should have

```
double CalcCircleArea(double radius);

int main()
{
  ..
}

double CalcCircleArea(double radius) // <- no semicolon
{
  ..
}
```

Comment: Now im getting   the error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  for both functions

Comment: @EsMosca Did you un-nest the functions, or just remove the `;`?

Comment: I guess i didn't un-nest the functions  but i can't find any information on doing that

Comment: @EsMosca Jack showed you how in his answer.  Copy/paste the code for the functions so that they're not inside of `main`.